# Parsing XML for nested tags

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing, sqlite

I have an XML, I am getting data into the format as below :

```
<Question>
    <QuestionID>1</QuestionID>
    <QuestionType>Logic</QuestionType>
    <QuestionImage>http://mobilecms.hiteshi.com/IQ/xml/Logic/1/Question/q.jpg</QuestionImage>
    <QuestionText>1 Which is the Next image?</QuestionText>
    <AnswerImages Count="4">
        <Image>http://mobilecms.hiteshi.com/IQ/xml/Logic/1/Answer/a.jpg</Image>
        <Image>http://mobilecms.hiteshi.com/IQ/xml/Logic/1/Answer/b.jpg</Image>
        <Image>http://mobilecms.hiteshi.com/IQ/xml/Logic/1/Answer/c.jpg</Image>
        <Image>http://mobilecms.hiteshi.com/IQ/xml/Logic/1/Answer/d.jpg</Image>
    </AnswerImages>
    <Answer>d</Answer>
    <Score>1</Score>
    <DifficultyLevel>1</DifficultyLevel>
</Question>
```

I have to read that XML and store all tags data into Two different tables of sqlite. I can easily read Main tags like QuestionID, QuestionType etc, and stores it into tableOne.

Now I want to read AnswerImages tag which is having count into it and it contents child tag named `<Image>` according to that count variable. Here I want to store all the `<Image>` tag data into tableTwo.

How can I store data into tableOne and tableTwo simultaneously?

Comment: Please, correct the links. If you don't know how to do it, check first, before posting. And personally, it's better to paste the xml here more than links.

Comment: What language are you using, and what platform? Are we to assume by your username that this is an iphone app?  Knowing the answer to those questions will help people in recommending what parser's are available so that you don't have to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

On an abstract level (without regarding any specific platform) you would deserialize your Xml to an object which then can be persisted to database by a Object-Relational-Mapper framework.